# How to access UI elements created by a List Adapter from an Activity?

Tags: android, adapter

In my code now, I have a DetailActivity, which simply calls a ListAdapter class to populate a ListView.

Within the ListAdapter class, I am inflating some custom views, some of which contain Buttons.

Back from within my DetailActivity, I would like to be able to access these buttons to enable/disable them depending on certain user actions.  Is there a way to do this?

I guess the larger question is: from an Activity, how can I grab a reference to any element (buttons, imageviews, textviews,etc) that are created from an Adapter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a `List<Object>` that is sent through the constructor of ListAdapter.
Just add a `boolean isEnable` to the `Object`, and then in your `getView()` method, add this line:

```
button.setEnabled(getItem(position).isEnable);
```

In your `DetailActivity`, you can change`isEnable` as you wish. And remember to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to get it worked.