# android fragments problems

Tags: java, android

i wrote a toDO list for my android class. It totally works , but now i want to display the todo list on a fragment ( so it can be its on tab). but when i tried making the fragment , i get a weird error when i try to run it. apparently the error comes from my main activity . so the way i have it set up is that, my main activity has a button that opens the fragment that has all the TOdolist stuff in it. but when i run it on my phone i get a unfortunately TodoList ha stopped as soon as it runs. the error is get is

```
06-10 22:21:51.284    5302-5302/com.example.mike.todolist D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-10 22:21:51.304    5302-5302/com.example.mike.todolist D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-10 22:21:51.304    5302-5302/com.example.mike.todolist W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417c2898)
06-10 22:21:51.314    5302-5302/com.example.mike.todolist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.mike.todolist.ToDoFragment.onCreateView(ToDoFragment.java:38)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)




my main activity look like

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;



public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.todo_main_activity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fragButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction
             =fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();    

                ToDoFragment fragment = new ToDoFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLL, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }


    }
```

My main activity xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLL"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="frag"
        android:id="@+id/fragButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="fragButtonClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />




</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment.java

```
package com.example.mike.todolist;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.mike.todolist.db.Contract;
import com.example.mike.todolist.db.DBHelper;

/**
 * Created by mike on 6/10/15.
 */
public class ToDoFragment extends ListFragment {
    public ListAdapter listAdapter;
    public DBHelper helper;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        update();

        Button doneButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                View v = (View) view.getParent();
                TextView taskTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
                String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();


                String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
                        Contract.TABLE_NAME,
                        Contract.Columns.TASK,
                        task);


                helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
                update();
            }
        });

        Button addButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                switch (R.id.add_task) {
                    case R.id.add_task:
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle("Add a task");
                        builder.setMessage("What would you like to do?");
                        final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
                        builder.setView(input);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                String task = input.getText().toString();

                                helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
                                SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                                cv.clear();
                                cv.put(Contract.Columns.TASK, task);

                                db.insertWithOnConflict(Contract.TABLE_NAME, null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                                update();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                        builder.create().show();


                }



            }
        });

        return view;


    }
    private void update() {
        helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(Contract.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Contract.Columns._ID, Contract.Columns.TASK},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{Contract.Columns.TASK},
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

and this is my fragmentlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLL"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Task"
        android:id="@+id/AddButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="AddButtonClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

taskview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/taskTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/doneButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/doneButton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/doneButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/doneButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="DoneButtonClick"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is `ListView`?

Comment: use FragmentActivity.See my answer carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is extending to a ListActivity which requires the ListView element in the xml. Your purpose be best served by extending your MainActivity class to Activity and fragments (if any) to Fragments class....

Comment: What problem are you facing now ?

Comment: i updated my post with a new error im getting , when i run it, the program starts and when i press the frag button it crashes. so there something wrong in my ToDoFragment.java code. im asuming, if i read the log right.

Comment: I cannot find the views with the specified id in your code... Make sure you sync the xml and java ID properly i mean you must have the element with that id in your inflated xml which you specify in java else it will raise a NPE or CCE

Comment: final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);  is what im using in my fragment java, fragmentlayout is the layout im using for my fragment. as far as i can see , all my ids and views line up

Comment: You have a listview in your fragment and the id's you are talking about must be in that listview right ? Coz only a button and a list view is what your fragmentlayout xml contains...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466377/how-can-i-access-ui-elements-of-a-fragment-inside-of-a-custom-adapter-from-an-ac

Answer (score 1):

According to android developers official website ([HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html))

> > ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view **MUST contain a ListView object** with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

**for example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

So either add a listview to your list activity xml or if you don't need a list view in your activity then simply use **FragmentActivity** to hold fragments.There is no point in using ListActivity unless it holds a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

> use Activity or FragmentActivity instead of ListActivity

if you want to use ListActivity [see here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/listactivity/android-listactivity-example/) once. you can use ListActivity without setting content view (setContentView()). you can directly setAdapter. or else use your own layout having one ListView with id as `"@android:id/list"`

**EDIT :**

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                TextView taskTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);//directly use 'view' if 'R.id.taskTextView'it present in 'view'

                String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();

                String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
                        Contract.TABLE_NAME,
                        Contract.Columns.TASK,
                        task);


                helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
                update();
            }
```

Comment: alright guys, i replaced the listactiviy with activity and it worked. i can now see my screen with the frag button on it. but , now when i hit that frag button , it crashes and i get this

Comment: have you written "fragButtonClick" method inside of activity..?

Comment: yes just put up all my code , i have the button and everything working. it jut crashes when i hit the frag button

Comment: this was the first thing i tried , i still get an error.. ill update on top what my error is now

Comment: my bad, i forgot to add the task_view xml i have that the done button is part off. ill put it up top

Answer (score 0):

Add an list view to your xml with id `android.R.id.list`

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

add this xml to your layout

Comment: If activity extends with `ListActivity` then no need to put listView in xml file.

Comment: But he has list in his fragment not in activity